# Need assistance on Return statement

Tags: javascript, return

Code :

```js
const array = [80, 50, 80];

function something() {
  let add = 0;
  for (let sum of array)

    add = add + sum;
  let average = add / array.length;
  console.log(average);

  if (average < 71) return "F";

}

something();
```

Output:

70

---

Please help me why the return statement doesn't return F

Comment: `console.log(something())`

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returns the value, but you do not use this value.

```js
const array = [80, 50, 80];

function something() {
  let add = 0;
  for (let sum of array)

    add = add + sum;
  let average = add / array.length;
  console.log(average);

  if (average < 71) return "F";

}

console.log(something());
```